# Can I create a shortcut to "troubleshoot network connection"?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch-file

I have a VM which very often needs the network adapter resetting (off topic here). I do this:
[image]

It takes a few clicks to initiate it then click through the resulting dialog. Is there a way I could create a little script and shortcut that would - for instance - throw up a command prompt window for a few seconds then disappear when complete?

I am assuming Powershell but perhaps a batch file would suffice (I never used Powershell).

Answer (score 1):

This should launch the troubleshooter:

```
msdt.exe -id NetworkDiagnosticsNetworkAdapter
```

but it still needs to know other stuff (i.e. if you have more than one adapter, which one needs troubleshooting). It would help to know what sort of problem you wish to remedy, flushdns? disable/re-enable a certain adapter? To disable and re-enable an adapter, find your adapter name with:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Look at Interface Name column, use that name with:

```
netsh interface set interface "YOUR-ADAPTER-NAME" disable
netsh interface set interface "YOUR-ADAPTER-NAME" enable
```

Comment: The option I show in my image seems to trouble-shoot everything (or figure out on its own) is there a way to do that via commandline?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit

Disable / enable your network interface named ethernet with a batch file. Must be run with admin privileges. It does the same thing as using the Device Manager to disable / enable a network adapter. When you are satisfied it is working comment / remove the lines you do not need.

```
@rem Disable / enable your network interface named ethernet. Must be run with admin privileges. Windows 10 64-bit.
netsh interface set interface ethernet admin=disable
netsh interface show interface
echo sleep 1 
timeout 1 > nul
netsh interface set interface ethernet admin=enable
netsh interface show interface
```

Disable / enable a network interface (ethernet or wi-fi) via the command line using a visual basic script. Does not require admin privileges. How to re-establish internet connection if you are using a wi-fi adapter and have turned off "Connect automatically when in range." Make your changes, save it as EnableDisableWireless.vbs, create a shortcut to it (f:\myapps\windows\EnableDisableWireless.vbs) and it will run right out of the box.

How to find your NIC (network interface card / network adapter / network interface name) name:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Change NIC_Name:

- `str_NIC_Name = "Wi-Fi 2"`

And if you are working on an ethernet adapter or you have **not** turned off "Connect automatically when in range" if using wi-fi comment out:

- `'WScript.Sleep 1000`
- `'Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`
- `'objShell.Run "%windir%\System32\netsh.exe wlan connect name=COM_000352 ssid=COM_000352"`
- `'Set objShell = Nothing`

If you are working on a wi-fi adapter and you **have** turned off "Connect automatically when in range":

How to find your NIC name and SSID:

```
netsh interface show interface
Netsh wlan show profiles
```

Change:

- `str_NIC_Name = "Wi-Fi 2"`
- `objShell.Run "%windir%\System32\netsh.exe wlan connect name=COM_000352 ssid=COM_000352"`

VBScript:

```
'~ Toggle a SPECIFIED NIC on or off. Re-establish internet connection if using wi-fi and you have turned off "Connect automatically when in range".
' https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/toggle-nic-on-off-with-vbs-xp-and-7.265836/
' Does not require admin privileges.

Option Explicit

Const NETWORK_CONNECTIONS = &H31&

Dim objShell, objFolder, objFolderItem, objEnable, objDisable
Dim folder_Object, target_NIC
Dim NIC, clsVerb
Dim str_NIC_Name, strEnable, strDisable
Dim bEnabled, bDisabled

' ========================================================
' ===== place the name of your network adapter here ======
' examples:
str_NIC_Name = "Wi-Fi 2"
' str_NIC_Name = "Ethernet"
' str_NIC_Name = "Local Area Connection 2"
' str_NIC_Name = "Local Area Connection"
' ========================================================

strEnable = "En&able"
strDisable = "Disa&ble"

' create objects and get items
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
Set folder_Object = objFolderItem.GetFolder

' see if the namespace exists
If folder_Object Is Nothing Then
    Wscript.Echo "Could not find Network Connections"
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set target_NIC = Nothing

' look at each NIC and match to the chosen name
For Each NIC In folder_Object.Items
    If LCase(NIC.Name) = LCase(str_NIC_Name) Then
        ' proper NIC is found, get it
        Set target_NIC = NIC
    End If
Next

If target_NIC Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "Unable to locate proper NIC"
    WScript.Quit
End If

bEnabled = True
Set objEnable = Nothing
Set objDisable = Nothing

For Each clsVerb In target_NIC.Verbs
    '~ Wscript.Echo clsVerb
    If clsVerb.Name = strEnable Then
        Set objEnable = clsVerb
        bEnabled = False
    End If
    If clsVerb.Name = strDisable Then
        Set objDisable = clsVerb
    End If
Next

If bEnabled Then
    objDisable.DoIt
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    ' run ping to prove wireless adapter is disabled
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "%windir%\system32\ping.exe 8.8.8.8"
    Set objShell = Nothing
Else
    objEnable.DoIt
' ========================================================
' ===== Begin if you are working on an ethernet adapter or you have **not** turned off "Connect automatically when in range" if using wi-fi comment out the following four lines:  ======
WScript.Sleep 1000
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%windir%\System32\netsh.exe wlan connect name=COM_000352 ssid=COM_000352"
Set objShell = Nothing
' =====    End if you are working on an ethernet adapter or you have **not** turned off "Connect automatically when in range" if using wi-fi comment out the following four lines:  ======
' ========================================================
End If 

'~ Give the connection time to stop/start
WScript.Sleep 1000
WScript.Quit
```

How to disable / enable a network adapter via the command line using a VBScript.

How to toggle a specified network adapter NIC on / off via the command line.

How to toggle a network adapter on / off via the command line.

How to toggle a specified network interface card on / off via the command line.